DBeaver - How To Bind Keyboard Shortcut For Query Script
Is there a way to bind a keyboard shortcut to go to the current open script on the right hand side of the screen?  I was able to bind a shortcut to take the current focus to the Database Navigator, but didn't see any option to do the same for the current displayed query.
